# How to let Android return an inner class object to flutter

Tags: java, flutter

I use Flutter to call Android third-party SDK，but i do not know how to get the value 'i' and 'info'  from the method `onCallback()` by Flutter.

---

***code***

```java
public static void registerWith(PluginRegistry.Registrar registrar) {
    channel = new MethodChannel(registrar.messenger(), CHANNEL);
    LivenessPlug instance = new LivenessPlug(registrar.activity());
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(instance);
}
```

```java
@Override
public void onMethodCall(MethodCall methodCall, MethodChannel.Result result) {
    if (methodCall.method.equals("getLivenessResult")) {
        try {
            getLivenessResult();
            result.success();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(activity, e.toString(), 2000).show();
        }
    }
    else {
        result.notImplemented();
    }
}

public void getLivenessResult() {
    OctopusLivenessManager.getInstance().
        detectLiveness(activity, new OctopusLivenessCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCallback(int i, OctopusLivenessInfo info) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    Log.e("result", info.verificationPackage);
                }
                Toast.makeText(activity, i + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
@SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
@Override
public void onMethodCall(MethodCall methodCall, MethodChannel.Result result) {
    if (methodCall.method.equals("getLivenessResult")) {
        try {
            getLivenessResult();
            result.success();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(activity, e.toString(), 2000).show();
        }
    }
    else {
        result.notImplemented();
    }
}
```